# Process information when interrupted: stack or process control block

Tags: process, stack, controls, block, interrupt

I am studying an Operating System course and we have this chapter about Processes. In this chapter we define the Process Control Block, which keeps the information about a process such as the program counter, content of registers, state, priority and so on. In this chapter it says that when the processor switches to another process (by interrupt), information will be saved in this process control block (PC, registers,...). In another chapter (1.4 Interrupts) it says when a process gets interrupted the PSW, PC and registers get put on the stack and when processor retakes control of this process it takes it from the stack.

It seems to be there are 2 different explanations here for what happens when an interrupt occurs. Do they both happen simultaneously or what? Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance
Sander

Answer (score 0):

Think of an interrupt as a function call with the difference that it stores more information on the stack and occurs at any time breaking into the normal flow of the program instructions. So, if interrupt handler function decides just to return from the interrupt call, the state is restored from the stack.

Otherwise, if inside the interrupt call, OS decides to preempt the current user process, it saves all the process state to PCB and switch the stack to another process.

BTW, switching to another process can happen not only by interrupt but during any normal call to OS kernel API (syscall).

Comment: So where does the PCB of a certain process go when the processor takes control over a new process from the short-term queue? Does the PCB of that process stay in memory? 

So if I understand correctly, information gets put on stack if it's an interrupt, meaning the process has not been paused, but processor is assigned to e.g. an I/O-controller and information gets put in the PCB (or updated) when the whole process is paused (interrupt or sys call?) and another process takes its place in the processor?

Comment: PCB is  always in memory. It can be a part of the kernel stack according to http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I have an exam about Operating Systems (Stallings) on monday and the information you provided will certainly help me with understanding!